# How do I increase the performance of this query with a LEFT clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `TA`, with two columns `C1` & `C2`. TA has 100 million plus rows. I run a query which fetches `DISTINCT` rows in `C1 WHERE LEFT(C2, 5) = 'XXXXX'`. I am facing issues with performance. it takes a couple of seconds to fetch the distinct data.

How do I increase the performance of this query?

Comment: care to provide the complete schema for the table? no point suggesting something you've already done.

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE C2 LIKE 'XXXXX%'` with an index on C2?  An index that _includes_ the data in the `DISTINCT` clause may help.

Comment: +1 HABO With an index on C2, that will be a seek every time.

Comment: What kind of string length distribution do you have?  If they are fairly short then the `LIKE` condition, which optimizes to a "starting with" index lookup, should perform well.  If the strings are fairly long then you might want to combine Robert Harvey's suggestion of an additional indexed column (with more keys per page since they are just the first 5 characters) and add a trigger to maintain the column automagically.

Comment: @HABO - The like clause was going to be my answer. You really should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the table/column definition?

Answer (score 2):

Add a new text column to your table, and run an `UPDATE` query that puts the result of `LEFT(C2, 5)` into that column.  Index the column, and run a new query `WHERE new_column = 'XXXXX'`.

Comment: or create a calculated bit field

Answer (score 2):

In general, you don't want to use a string function in your WHERE clause.

You don't mention if C2 is indexed. At least if it's indexed, the function can be applied against the index without having to read every row in the table (a scan) in order to see if it matches your condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can also index the column that you have, and then try to do something like:

```
where c2 >= 'XXXXX' and
      c2 < 'XXXXY'
```

Or:

```
where c2 >= 'XXXXX' and
      c2 <= 'XXXXXZ'
```

The idea is to switch the query from a function on a column to a range.  If you have an index, then the range filter can use an index on the column.